# How to select distinct years in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    name AS Name,
    SUM(number) AS number_of_names
FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` 
WHERE 
    name = 'Jacob'
    AND year > 2003
    AND year < 2008
GROUP BY 
    name
```

So this is the query I am trying to run but I can't for the life of me figure out to select the specific years all in one query. Like the outputs of each year distinctly laid out. So the output would be

```
2003 Jacob 1203123
2004 Jacob 123123
2005 Jacob 123123
2006 Jacob 1231239
2007 Jacob 123123
2008 Jacob 12312
```

Data is from here : https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/social-security-administration/us-names

Comment: Did you try grouping by the year as well, to start? Also, if a year is greater than 2003, it is also great than 2008 so you only need `year > 2003` unless I am missing something.

Comment: Please tag your specific RDBMS and include sample data

Comment: Sorry @chrisbyte was just error in my example.

Comment: @stu Added the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. You need to `GROUP BY name, year` to get a distinct sum for a name for every year. Also, `>= 2003` and `<= 2008` makes the query inclusive, otherwise it will skip the years 2003 and 2008 respectively.

```
SELECT 
    name AS Name, 
    year as Year,
    sum (number ) AS number_of_names
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` 
WHERE name = 'Jacob'
AND year >= 2003
AND year <= 2008
GROUP BY name, year
ORDER BY  year
```

Comment: What if i wanted to return proportions of the population? instead of the sum?